# Elasticsearch can't recognize phrase terms?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to count how many times or how many documents my `terms or keywords` occurred from my specified query

**Here's my "content" field's mapping**

[image: Content Field Mapping]

Here's my aggregation query:

```
"aggs" => [
    "KEYWORDS" => [
        "filters" => [
            "filters" => [
                "term1" => [
                    "term" => [
                        'content' => "isko"
                    ]
                ],
                "term2" => [
                    "term" => [
                        'content' => "manila"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

and here's the response:

[image: Output 1]

I'm almost near to my desired output, however when I wanted the **right** phrase / keywords, it is not being recognized by Elasticsearch

```
"aggs" => [
    "KEYWORDS" => [
        "filters" => [
            "filters" => [
                "term1" => [
                    "term" => [
                        'content' => "mayor isko moreno"
                    ]
                ],
                "term2" => [
                    "term" => [
                        'content' => "mayor vico sotto"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

*response*

[image: Output 2]

Does this mean Elasticsearch can't recognize phrases?

Here's my whole query:
[My ES Query](https://pastebin.com/pxy8d1s2)

Comment: What type of syntax is that? Do you use the REST API?

Comment: hello! I'm using Laravel (a PHP-based Framework) so I suppose I'm using the official Elasticsearch PHP API (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php)

Comment: What type does the `content` type field have?

Comment: hello sir @Val I edited the post, you may now see the `content` field's mapping

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html):

> Returns documents that contain an exact term in a provided field.

Terms query does not parse the query string, it is looking for an exact match.
However your strings appear to be index'd with the default analyzer (i'm assuming seeing as your single word queries work as expected). meaning their content is stored "as single words" loosely speaking.

You need to query the `content.keyword` field which is unalyzed to get an exact match for the entire phrase.

Comment: did not work with the `content.keyword` technique sir :( any other possible solutions?

Comment: It should work assuming the string is an exact match to the entry one, however another option you can do is use [regexp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) on `content.keyword` like so `".*phrase.*", this is not as efficient as a terms query and its just a work around to a non exact match, which as explained should not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are filtering with exact content, then try to apply the filter on non-analyzed fields, that will serve your purpose.
below is the code.

```
"aggs" => [
    "KEYWORDS" => [
        "filters" => [
            "filters" => [
                "term1" => [
                    "term" => [
                        'content.keyword' => "mayor isko moreno"
                    ]
                ],
                "term2" => [
                    "term" => [
                        'content.keyword' => "mayor vico sotto"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: This works provided the value of the content field is all lowercase, otherwise you'd need an additional [`lowercase` normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html) to make it happen

Comment: tried adding the `.keyword` in my `content` field, did not work, still displays 0 for the `doc_count` :(

Comment: can you please post some sample indexed documents.

Comment: Hello @ShashankReddy here's a sample code https://ibb.co/PYMj2xR

Comment: Ok so it's not exact match. You have two options: 1) either use [`match_phrase`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) or 2) index 3-gram [shingles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html)

Comment: sir @Val the closest output is the `match_phrase`, and I'm more lenient to use it due to ease of use, however, the `match_phrase` is not **case insensitive**, how can we make it case insensitive?

Comment: `match_phrase` is definitely case insensitive, but you need to run it on the `content` field not `content.keyword`

Comment: Here's now the output with `match_phrase` https://ibb.co/K60hn94 but the problem is, there's one document that has a content of `mayor Vico Sotto` so the `doc_count` was not accurate: https://ibb.co/WxMxr8w it missed a document where it doesnt have the same case

Comment: yes sir @Val, I run it with `content` and not `content.keyword`

Comment: I'm already at 99% of fulfilling my goal, it's just that the `match_phrase` is case insensitive, may you suggest any additional scripts to make it case insensitive so I can gather all matching phrase, sir @Val?

Comment: can you update your question with the current query your running?

Comment: added the query through a link sir, but for your convenience, here it is: https://pastebin.com/ffTDwE94

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200338/discussion-between-jueviole17-and-val).

Comment: hello sir @Val may you kindly post an answer below so I can vote for it? The technique to change the mappings and add a `lowercase` did the trick. well not exactly, but we did a custom `whitespace` + `lowercase` normalizer